# Email to list / column in Trello (not email to board or email to card)

Tags: trello, trello-organization

I've got a Trello board with multiple lists / columns, what I'm trying to do is email a new card to specific lists / columns based on the output of another 3rd party programme, eg. under some circumstances email a card to column 1, under other circumstances email to list / column 2.. etc.

The logic part of it in the other programme works fine, the bit I'm having an issue with is actually how to email to a specific list / column, at the moment I can see how to email to board (which allows you to set a list / column, but this only seems to allow you to set 1 list / column as the default for the email to board) and also email to card.

Any idea if it is possible to email to list / column?

Answer (score 2):

If you can control the text in the email subject, you could use [Butler Bot](https://trello.com/b/2dLsEE9t/butlerbot-for-trello) to automate moving the card to the right list by prepending a text to the subject of each email.

For example, let's say that you want to email a card with the title "Card title", which would go in the subject of the email, and a description that goes in the body of the email. If you can get the 3rd party programme to change the subject to "(List 1) Card title", then you can create a command in Butler Bot such as:

`when a card starting with "(List 1)" is emailed in, move it to "List 1"`

You would need to create several rules in Butler Bot, one for each target list.

A disadvantage of this is that the "(List 1)" would stay in the card title, but depending on your application this may be acceptable.

Disclosure: I'm the author of Butler Bot.